# What is the number of the possible outcomes of solving the four true or false questions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, permutations

A section of an exam contains four true or false questions. A completed exam paper is selected at random and four answers are recorded.
What is the number of the possible outcomes of solving the four true or false questions ?
eg. the number of outcomes ={TTFT,TTFF,.......}
Now what is the number of this outcomes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: There are 2 choices as answer to every question and there are 4 questions in total. Hence no. of outcomes = $2^4$

Comment: thanks , but I know this way and I want to solve it by using permutations techniques, Can you help me ?

Comment: This itself is a permutation technique. What way else do you want?

Comment: I don't know , but I want another solution than this law